# ReactJs - Not able to display all data at once. The loop to get the data runs automatically by re-rendering one by one and stops at the last data set

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, google-cloud-firestore

[Image of my ReactJS web page and the console view to see the data structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2pfI.png)

**My code below:**

```
    import React, {
  Component,
  useState,
  useEffect
} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import {
  Card,
  CardImg,
  CardText,
  CardBody,
  CardTitle,
  CardSubtitle,
  Button
} from 'reactstrap';
import Image from 'react-image-resizer';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';


class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {

    };
  }


   async getOrderbookData() {
      try{
       var clientArray = ['Client1', 'Client2', 'Client3', 'Client4', 
                        'Client5', 'Client6', 'Client7'];
    for (var i=0; i<clientArray.length; i++) {
    const db = firebase.firestore();
    await db.collection('Orderbook').get().then((querySnapshot) => {
      var orderbooks = []
      var orderbook = []     
         querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
            orderbooks.push(doc.data())
              console.log('THISS'+ orderbooks)    
      });
       orderbook = orderbooks[i].body
       console.log('i value:' + i);

      this.setState({
          orderbook: orderbook
      })
    });
   }
    }catch (err) {
       return "Error:" + err
   }
  }

  async componentDidMount() {

    this.getMarginData()

    this.getOrderbookData()

   }



  render() {
    return ( 
      <div className = "App" >

          <Image src={ require('./investsaathilogo.png')} 
          height = {100} width = {100}/>

        <h2> Orderbook Data </h2> 

              <h5 className="container"> 
          {
            console.log('ORDERBOOKNOW' + this.state.orderbook),

        this.state.orderbook && this.state.orderbook.map((order, key) =>
          <div key={order + key}> 

          <li>BuySell: {order.BuySell}</li>

        </div> 

         )     
         }
             </h5> 

            </div>
        );
      }
     }

    export default App;
```

Now I am able to display the data for all clients and all their orders one by one. But React automatically re-renders the data one after the other. Does anyone know how to display all the clients data at once instead of it going through the loop automatically and stopping and displaying the last item of data in the loop?

Comment: Why are you doing this: `JSON.stringify(this.state.margins).map` ??

Comment: Hello Azium,  if I don't json.stringify it doesn't render and display on the page. So I cant display without that and then can't map it.

Comment: Can someone please help with the updated question and problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can't `JSON.stringify` something and map. Rather do something like this,

```js
import React, {
  Component,
  useState,
  useEffect
} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import {
  Card,
  CardImg,
  CardText,
  CardBody,
  CardTitle,
  CardSubtitle,
  Button
} from 'reactstrap';
import Image from 'react-image-resizer';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';


class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {}
  }

  getMarginData() {

    const db = firebase.firestore();
    return db.collection('Margin').get().then((querySnapshot) => {
      const margins = []
      querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
        margins.push(doc.data())

        console.log(margins);
      });

      this.setState({
        margins: margins
      })

    });

  }

  getOrderbookData() {

    const db = firebase.firestore();
    return db.collection('Orderbook').get().then((querySnapshot) => {
      const orderbooks = []
      querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
        orderbooks.push(doc.data())

        console.log(orderbooks);
      });

      this.setState({
        orderbooks: orderbooks[0]
      })

    });
  }


  componentDidMount() {

    this.getMarginData()
    this.getOrderbookData()

  }

  render() {
    return ( 
      <div className = "App" >

          <Image src={ require('./investsaathilogo.png')} height = {100} width = {100}/>

          <p>
              <h2> Margin Data </h2>
              <h5> 
                {this.state.margins && this.state.margins.map((margin, index) =>
                  <div key = {margin.Client1.ALB} > < /div>            
                )} 
              </h5>
          </p>

          <p>
              <h2> Orderbook Data </h2> 
              <card>
                  <h5> {JSON.stringify(this.state.orderbooks)} </h5> 
              </card> 
          </p>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Hi bonnopc, let me try this and get back to you. Thanks.

Comment: So it doesn't show any error but it also does not render anything, it's just blank. Any idea why? Would really appreciate your reply.

Comment: So with the code below I am able to display the data as a string with extra special characters as it just shows blank if i try to iterate through it without JSON.stringify. Can you please tell me how to fix this.                                                                          
                                                                                                          
this.state.margins && this.state.margins.map((margin, index) =>
                  <div key={margin + index}> 
                    <li> {JSON.stringify(margin)}</li>           
                  </div>